# "Curry" from tuple in SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, mosml

I am trying to define a function wrapper that curries a tuple in SML.

```
fun curry f = fn (x, y) z => f x y z;
```

Gives me the error

> Non-identifier applied to a pattern.

I am new to ML and not sure why the pattern matching in `fn` doesn't work.

How could I make this work?

Comment: Anonymous functions can only take one parameter. What is `z` doing there?

Comment: Also, currying usually means transforming a function from `a * b -> c` into `a -> b -> c`, not from `a -> b -> c -> d` into `a * b -> c -> d`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to define a function wrapper that curries a tuple in SML.
>
> ```
> fun curry f = fn (x, y) z => f x y z;
> ```
>
> How could I make this work?

Closures in SML don't allow for multiple arguments, but you can nest them instead.

What `curry` usually does is take a function `f` that normally accepts a tuple `(x, y)` and instead returns a modified function that takes `x` and `y` separately. Here is a number of equivalent ways to define `curry`:

```
fun curry f x y = f (x, y)
fun curry f x = fn y => f (x, y)
fun curry f = fn x => fn y => f (x, y)
val curry = fn f => fn x => fn y => f (x, y)
```

Its opposite, `uncurry` instead takes a function `f` that takes `x` and `y` separately and returns a modified function that takes `(x, y)`. Here is one way to write `uncurry`:

```
fun uncurry f (x, y) = f x y
```

It's easy to mix up the two.

One way to fix the function you've written so that it compiles is insert an extra `=> fn`:

```
fun what_is_this f = fn (x, y) => fn z => f x y z
                            (* ^- there *)
```

Before giving it a name, let's analyse what it does. It has the type signature:

```
fn : ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) -> 'a * 'b -> 'c -> 'd
                  (* now a tuple -^    ^- still curried *)
```

meaning that it takes a function of three curried arguments (`x`, `y` and `z`) and returns a modified function where the first two arguments are now in a tuple (uncurried) and the third is still curried. This is really a less generic version of **`uncurry`**. A more clear way of writing it would be:

```
fun what_is_this f (x, y) z = f x y z
```

If you use `uncurry` on a function of three arguments, you get the same effect, but you can't use `what_is_this` on anything with two curried arguments. So I'd say that this is a less useful variant of `uncurry`.

There are however other more useful variants of `curry`/`uncurry`. For example, you could make an `uncurry_twice` that converts `f x y z` into `(uncurry_twice f) ((x, y), z)`, or an `uncurry3` that converts `f x y z` into `(uncurry3 f) (x, y, z)`:

```
fun uncurry_twice f = uncurry (uncurry f)
fun uncurry3 f (x, y, z) = f x y z
```

Comment: You put so much love into this! Thank you.